# SAS Printing to a Custom Report

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a custom text report from my sas code, below is the code

```
data have ;
  ncandidates=1; ngames=3; controlppt=1; controlgame=2;
  ppt1='Abc'; ppt2='Bcd';
  infile cards dsd dlm='|';
  input (var1-var21) ($);
cards;
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
;
filename report 'myreport.txt';
data _null_;
  file report dsd dlm='|' LRECL=8614;
  a='';
  put
    83*'#'
  / '##### Number of ppts'
  / 83*'#'
  / 'input.Name=' @
  ;
  eof = 0;
  do until(eof);
  set have end=eof;
  If not missing(var1) then
  put var1-var10 @@ ;
  end;

  put a
 // 83*'#'
  / '##### Output Data'
  / 83* '#'
 // 'output.Name=' @;

  eof=0;
  do until(eof);
  set have ;
  If not missing(var11) then
  put var11-var20 @@  ;
  end;
  put '1';

run;
```

Everything gets printed to the file except for the last put '1';
Nothing after the second do until block gets executed; 
Also, if I add `end=eof` to the last do until block then everything gets printed twice.

Do we have a solution around this?

Comment: You don't need double @. Single will do. The '1' is being printed at the end of the line with the data since you did not use the / instruction to start a new line.  To prevent the extra execution of the first PUT statement you need to add a STOP statement at the end of your data step to prevent SAS from running a second iteration of your data step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the cause of the issue. But sometimes SAS behaves weird if a dataset is read several times as you do it. But using a different variable for second `set have end=eof2;` resolves the problem:

```
data have ;
  ncandidates=1; ngames=3; controlppt=1; controlgame=2;
  ppt1='Abc'; ppt2='Bcd';
  infile cards dsd dlm='|';
  input (var1-var21) ($);
cards;
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b1|2|a|1|3|b
;
filename report '~/myreport.txt';
data _null_;
  file report dsd dlm='|' LRECL=8614;
  a='';
  put
    83*'#'
  / '##### Number of ppts'
  / 83*'#'
  / 'input.Name=' @
  ;
  eof = 0;
  do until(eof);
  set have end=eof;
  If not missing(var1) then
  put var1-var10 @@ ;
  end;

  put a
 // 83*'#'
  / '##### Output Data'
  / 83* '#'
 // 'output.Name=' @;

  eof2=0;
  do until(eof2);
  set have end=eof2;
  If not missing(var11) then
  put var11-var20 @@  ;
  end;
  put '1';

  stop;
run;
```

Comment: It prints the content twice, i guess from both the set statements, that is what I need to get rid of.

Comment: It's not printed twice, because I put `stop;` statement before run. Could you double check, otherwise it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added stop to my code and it prevented from outputting it twice, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A 'plain' DATA step stops when a read is attempted after the last record of a set has been read.  This typically happens during the implicit loop that is inherent in the magic of a DATA step.  When you loop over a set explicitly with end of data checks, the read attempt beyond does not occur, and thus does not implicitly end the step.

The eof flag is changed only when the end of data is reached.  It is not set to 0 when not at end of data -- the eof flag is simply what it is at the start of the loop.  Thus the flag needs to be reset if reused for a subsequent loop.

```
* 'top' is logged twice;
* the data step ends when the second implicit iteration tries to read past eof of the first set;

data _null_;
  put 'top';

  do until (eof);
    set sashelp.class(obs=2) end=eof;
    put name=;
  end;

  eof = 0; * reset flag;
  do until (eof);
    set sashelp.class(where=(name=:'J')) end=eof;
    put name=;
  end;
run;


* 'top' is logged once;
* the data step ends when the stop is reached at the bottom;

data _null_;
  put 'top';

  do until (eof);
    set sashelp.class(obs=2) end=eof;
    put name=;
  end;

  eof = 0;
  do until (eof);
    set sashelp.class(where=(name=:'J')) end=eof;
    put name=;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: I had done that in my code above, but it prints the text twice.

Comment: The program in the question does not have the STOP statement to prevent SAS from running the second iteration of the data step.